# Trying to connect to MSSQL server with PHP8 / ODBC Driver 18 with no SSL

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL server.
The server MSSQL server doesnt have SSL option active, so I am trying to connect to it with no SSL.

Edit -> The OS is Centos9

I am using **PHP 8.0.20**
As driver to connect to  the MSSQL server I am using **ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server**

The code I am trying to use is:

```
<?php

 $serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
 $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"mydatabse","UID"=>"myuser","PWD"=>"mypassword","Encrypt"=>false,"TrustServerCertificate"=>false);
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
 if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

 $sql = "select * from table";
 $params = array(1, "some data");

 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
 if( $stmt === false ) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
?>
```

The output I got is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol]
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
        )

)
```

How can I connect to the MSSQL by using PHP 8.0.20 and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Serve with no SSL.

Thank You all!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is caused by the database server having an older version of SSL that is no longer supported by v18.  I don't think there is a way to disable SSL completely, and the suggested way is to connect with SSL but using a self-signed cert (and connecting with `TrustServerCertificate` enabled).

No matter, personally I have always had issues with the official implementations by Microsoft in PHP.  I use the excellent FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib driver instead.

Here's an example using PDO, which I recommend either way as it allows you to use the same code to connect to different servers using different drivers.  I have included example connection strings for using the official drivers as well, but commented out.

```php
$host = 'x.x.x.x';
$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';
$db = 'xxx';

//$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server={$host};Database={$db};Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes";
//$dsn = "odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server={$host};Database={$db};Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes";

$dsn = "dblib:host={$host};dbname={$db}";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

    $query = "select @@version";

    foreach($dbh->query($query) as $row)
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    print "PDO ERROR: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
}
```

More info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

You should be able to install it on CentOS using
`sudo dnf install php-pdo-dblib.x86_64`

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions. I will try them and comeback to you!